# Yahoo Boss API Pagination?

Tags: php, json, pagination, yahoo-api, yahoo-boss-api

I use the code in php to connect to the api and display the results...

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require("OAuth.php"); 
    $cc_key  = "cc_key"; //cc_key
    $cc_secret = "cc_secret"; // cc_secret key
    $url = "https://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web";
    $args = array();
    $args["q"] = htmlspecialchars($_GET["q"]);
    $args["format"] = "json";
    $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($cc_key, $cc_secret);
    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"GET", $url, $args);
    $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, NULL);
    $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($args));
    //echo $url . "<br>"; test uri
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array($request->to_header());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $rsp = curl_exec($ch);
    $results = json_decode($rsp, true);

//force to assoc-array, which will allow array-access
foreach($results['bossresponse']['web']['results'] as $result)
{
    //$result is array here, but do the same stuff
echo '<a href="'.$result['url'].'" target=\'_blank\'>'.$result['title'].'</a></br>';
echo ''.$result['abstract'].'</br>';
echo '<a href="'.$result['url'].'" target=\'_blank\'>'.$result['dispurl'].'</a></br>';

}
?>
```

then write mini "pagination"

```
//$start = "&start=" . "0";
$start_val = $_GET['start'];
if ($start_val == "") $start_val = 0;
$start = "&start=" . $start_val;
// Some more code...
$count_val = 10;
$count = "&count=" . $count_val;

if ($query != "") {
if ($start_val != 0) {
echo '<a href="?query='.$_GET['query'] . '&start='. (intval($start_val) - intval($count_val))  .'">previous</a>';
echo '<span> | </span>';
}
echo '<a href="?query='.$_GET['query'] . '&start='.(intval($start_val) + intval($count_val)) . '">next</a>';
}
```

but "pagination" does not work =(
I can not understand why does not work

My question is how do I paginate results, since all the 50 results appear on the first web page only. I want to display ten results in every page.

**Please HELP me**

Thanks.

Comment: Its safer to use `if (empty($var))` than `if ($var == '')`. You can also `var_dump()` to make sure your variables hold the information you expect, or do it test-like with `assert()`